# Unknown Provider error when injecting provider from a foreign module into config block

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two modules, `module A` and `module B`, who depend on each other.

`Module A` is being `bootstrapped`. `Module A` defines a `provider` which I want to inject into the config block of `module B`. But I only get `Unknown provider` errors:

```
Failed to instantiate module A due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module B due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: testProvider`
```

Here is the [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/chIoJeFpyo4MfFjkduHx), it's super simple, but I don't get why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the A module depends of B that himself depends of A. You can't do that, it's wrong.

Since you're A module doesn't really depends of B, just remove it from the declaration:

```
var A = angular.module('A', []);
```

The exception will go away.

You also need to change the `ng-app` value:

```
<html ng-app="B">
```

See [fixed Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SnK1KccV1Tj2ve5kCTn9?p=preview).

Comment: The problem is that in my real app I have one main module (A) and then not one but several sub-modules (B), who all run their own config blocks to register their own sub-states in ui router. Now I wanted to add a provider to my main module that can be injected in all the submodules to get configured. So I have cant bootstrap one of the submodules, they all have to be loaded & config blocks run.

Comment: Why don't you create a C module and inject it in the B modules ?